# Javascript [CANVAS] "Slow down framerate?"

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, paint

how are you? I'm struggling with a little problem I have with my code. I'm asked to create a paint program with javascript and I'm almost there but I'm struggling with how fast it paints. I have it painting so that it draws something on every mouseDrag event at clients x and y position.

[Sample Paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaHLJ.png)

See how the sample paint's shapes are defined and you can see each one, here is my program after drawn on canvas.

Here is mine, it paints way too fast.

[My Paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owNXc.png)

```
if(dragging && type.options[type.selectedIndex].value == "squares") {
            ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
            ctx.lineWidth = 5;        
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(e.clientX, e.clientY, 40, 40);    
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could save the time of each draw and whenever you would potentially draw again, check if enough time has passed since the last paint.

Here is an example:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
const speedInput = document.getElementById('draw-speed');
let buffer = +speedInput.value;
let lastPaint;

ctx.canvas.onmousemove = ({ x, y }) => {
    const now = Date.now();
    if (!lastPaint || (now - lastPaint) > buffer) {
        lastPaint = now;
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
    }
};

speedInput.onchange = ({ target }) => { 
    buffer = +target.value; 
};
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
label {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<label for="draw-speed">Draw speed</label>
<select id="draw-speed">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>50</option>
    <option selected>100</option>
    <option>150</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hey, could I get some further help please? My email is akradhak@ucsc.edu

Comment: @SravyaVummadi If my post answers your question, please accept it. If you need help getting it to work for your use-case, please use the comments to ask for clarification. And if you have an unrelated or follow-up question, please create a new post.